# new game won't refresh high score from py file, but it will when reopen game. why?

Tags: python

i also checked the py file is updated after saving new best score pleas help thank you
The code without the game itself i have tried reopening the game and after reopening it refreshed the high score.

```
gamecount = 1
savedscore = ''
savedname = ''
addname = ''
bestscore = 'No Best Score Yet'
```

#### Title

```
print 'Welcome to the Code Breaker!', '\n' 'Good luck!'
```

#### LOAD HIGHSCORE

```
while True:
    if (os.path.isfile('highscore.py')):
        import highscore

        bestscore = highscore.savedscore
        addname = highscore.savedname
    else:
        pass
```

#### Code for the game

```
****
```

#### Bestscore

```
    if guesscount < bestscore:
        bestnewscore = guesscount
        print  'New Best Score!:', guesscount
        addnewname = raw_input('Enter name:')
```

#### SAVE

```
        savescore = raw_input('To Save Best Score Press "S" and "Enter"\nor to Skip Press "Enter"')
        if savescore == 's':
            def main():

                f = open("highscore.py", "w")
                savedname = addnewname
                f.write('savedname = '"'{}'"''.format(savedname))
                f.write('\n')
                savedscore = bestnewscore
                f.write('savedscore = {}'.format(savedscore))
                f.close()


            if __name__ == "__main__":
                print 'Saved!'
                main()
        else:
            pass



    else:
        pass
```

#### NEWGAME

```
    newgame = raw_input('For a new game press "N" and "Enter" or press "Enter" to exit')

    if newgame == 'n':
        gamecount += 1
        import highscore

        bestscore = highscore.savedscore
        addname = highscore.savedname



        continue
    else:
        break
```

### #

Comment: It's a bad way of saving user data...you must use pickle or a database to store and retrieve user information...

Comment: You want to try the imp module if you want to stick with your current method so you can reload the module each time. `import imp` and `imp.reload(highscore)`

Comment: OK thank you i will learn about it more i am just a beginner. If you have a link to start with would be nice.

Comment: @Wright: [`imp.reload(module)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/imp.html#imp.reload): "Deprecated since version 3.4: Use [`importlib.reload()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) instead."  (But best would be to not store user data in Python code at all.)

Comment: thank you @Wright, `import imp` and `imp.reload(highscore)` works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Change your new game to:

```
import pickle
newgame = raw_input('For a new game press "N" and "Enter" or press "Enter" to exit')

    if newgame == 'n':
        gamecount += 1
        data = {'savedname' = addnewname, 'savedscore' = bestnewscore}
        with open("DATA.dat","rb") as file:
             data = pickle.load(file)   
             bestscore = data['savedname']
             addname = data['savedscore']

        continue
    else:
        break
```

Change you SAVE to this:

```
import pickle

savescore = raw_input('To Save Best Score Press "S" and "Enter"\nor to Skip Press "Enter"')
if savescore == 's':
    def main():
        data = {'savedname' = addnewname, 'savedscore' = bestnewscore}
        with open("DATA.dat","wb") as file:
            pickle.dump(data,file)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print 'Saved!'
        main()
else:
    pass
```

And one more TIP you dont need to close a file when you use with-as statement.Python does it automatically for you..

Comment: thanks a lot i have to learn more about pickle for now i will just use what @Wright said